# Event handlers are not fired

Tags: grails

I'm trying to get familiar with Grails events which are defined in scripts/_Events.groovy file.
The problem is my events hooks are ignored.
The file is definitely compiled because Grails complains about syntax errors if they are.
But there is nothing more. I can't notice any difference in execution of commands like "grails war" and "grails run-app".

Grails version is 2.4.4

```
includeTargets << grailsScript('_GrailsPackage')
includeTargets << grailsScript('_GrailsEvents')

eventCompileStart = { kind ->
    println "Triggered ${kind}"
    throw new IllegalArgumentException()
}

eventPackagingEnd = {
    println "PackaginEnd"
    throw new IllegalArgumentException()    
}


eventPackagingStart = {
    println "PackaginStart"
    throw new IllegalArgumentException()    
}

eventCreateWarStart = {warName, stagingDir ->
    println "eventCreateWarStart [${stagingDir}]"
    throw new IllegalArgumentException()    
}

eventCreateWarEnd = {warName, stagingDir ->
    println " eventCreateWarEnd ${stagingDir}"
    throw new IllegalArgumentException()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since some time I figured out that _Events.groovy file should be 1 level upper in the project structure. So the right place for scripts folder is the root project folder rather than grails-app one.